# GWT + mvp4g rewriting URL

Tags: gwt, url-rewriting, mvp4g

In my java web project we use spring + gwt + mvp4g. We have several users on site, each of them is able to see several pages:

- Profile: mysite.com/#profile?user=blabla
- Orders: mysite.com/#orders?user=blabla

and so on

History tokens "user", "orders" are handled by some @Presenter annotated class (according to mvp4g best practises : EventBus + HistoryConverter).
We want to provide each user some kind of personal space: mysite.com/blabla or blabla.mysite.com (assuming that "blabla" is unique for each user)

So links listed above should look in the following way:

- Profile: mysite.com/blabla/profile or blabla.mysite.com/
- Orders: mysite.com/blabla/orders or blabla.mysite.com/orders
  ...

How can achieve this?

**Solved by using custom mvp4g PlaceService**